# Using capybara-screenshot with apparition

Tags: rspec, capybara, apparition

I have seamlessly converted from `poltergeist` to the [apparition](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition) gem, but am using the `capybara-screenshot` gem to generate an html snapshot of the page when a test fails. I am seeing the warning:

```
capybara-screenshot could not detect a screenshot driver for 'apparition'. Saving with default with unknown results.
```

It turns out the default is OK, because the resultant screenshot is good.  How do I stop this warning message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the warning by using the master branch of capybara-screenshot.

```
gem 'capybara-screenshot', github: 'mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot'
```

Apparition is a new driver and isn't yet supported in a released version of `capybara-screenshot` - but was added to the code at the end of June - https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot/commit/273317b241d1d1d8600b32fad998742894424f3b